# CPDTDF in browser's User Agent

Tags: browser, user-agent

I'm seeing this **CPDTDF** fragment fairly frequently in my logs, and I haven't found any information about it. 
Does anybody know what it means?

Some real examples:

> Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0;
>   Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0;
>   PBSTB 1.2; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727;
>   .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR
>   3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; CPDTDF; InfoPath.2; .NET4.0C)
>
> Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0;
>   Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2;
>   .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR
>   3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; CPDTDF; Tablet PC 2.0; InfoPath.2; MSOffice 12
>
> Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0;
>   Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; GTB6.5;
>   SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR
>   3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; CPDTDF; Tablet PC 2.0; .NET4.0C;
>   AskTbSTC/5.9.1.14019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CPDTDF and similar (CPDTDF etc) are manufacturer OEM IDs. These CP ones mean Compaq

[See this link for a list of unknown user agent fragments](http://www.whatismybrowser.com/developers/unknown-user-agent-fragments)